# How to demonstrate that 3 vectors are total in $\mathbb C^3$

Tags: vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces, vector-analysis

I don't know if total is the right term. 
A set A is "total" if  $\langle f,a_i \rangle=0 \iff f=0$ .

I have those vectors: $c_1=(1,2,0), c_2=(0,1,2), c_3=(0,0,1)$ and I have to verify if they're "total" in $\mathbb C^3$.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following your definition of total, $\{c_1,c_2,c_3\}$ is total iif the matrix $$A=\begin{bmatrix} c_1 \\ c_2 \\ c_3\end{bmatrix}\in M_{3\times 3}(\mathbb{C})\cap M_{3\times 3}(\mathbb{R})$$ is non singular.
Infact if exists $f\in \mathbb{C^3}$ such that $Af=0$ then  $\langle c_i,\overline{f}\rangle = 0$ (by definition of $\langle,\rangle$ on $\mathbb{C^n}\times \mathbb{C}^n$) and viceversa.
So you only have to check that $detA\neq 0$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Are you familiar with this definition? Do you know if total is the right word? Translating from italian, it should be total or complete, but I didn't find much, unless about a metric space, which is not the case.

Comment: In studying Hilbert spaces one usually defines an Hilbert basis as a orthonormal system (a set of pairwise orthogonal vectors) that is maximal (or complete). Maximal is the same of your total.  Maybe it is used also total, I don't know.

Comment: I think it's this. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

For a finite-dimensional space $V$ and $A\subseteq V$ we have:

\begin{align}
A \text{ is total} &\iff \big(x \perp A \implies x = 0\big)\\
&\iff A^\perp = \{0\}\\
&\iff \mathrm{span}\, A = A^{\perp\perp} = \{0\}^\perp = V
\end{align}

So you just have to chech if $\mathrm{span}\,A = V$, or in this case if $\{c_1, c_2, c_3\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{C}^3$.